# Org Status=requested resource does not exist

Tags: vs-code, org, dev-hub

Yesterday, the all of the connected orgs that I had been using without issue had their statuses change to "The requested resource does not exist" in vs code. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the salesforce cli as well as the salesforce extension pack. When I authorize them, it says it was successful but the status does not change and I cannot use them. Any idea of what is going on here?

Comment: Where did you see this status change exactly? I don't recall seeing org status on the VSCode UI...